# Como usar um método da classe concreta criado a partir de uma interface?

Tags: c#, interface

Na classe **Advogado** implementei todas as propriedade e métodos da Interface **IPessoaFisica**, e mais algumas outras propriedades e métodos específicas da classe **Advogado**, como Advogar() e Oab.

Como acesso esse método? Sendo que na criação do objeto **Advogado** eu criei conforme TesteMethod abaixo:

```
public interface IPessoaFisica
{
    int PessoaId { get; set; }
    string Nome { get; set; }
    IEndereco Endereco { get; set; }
    IContato Contato { get; set; }
    string Cpf { get; set; }
    string Identidade { get; set; }
    char Sexo { get; set; }
}

//Classe Concreta
public class Advogado: IPessoaFisica
{
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public IEndereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public IContato Contato { get; set; }
    public char Sexo { get; set; }
    public string Identidade { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Oab { get; set; }

    public void Advogar()
    {
        //Fazer qualquer coisa
    }
}

public void TestMethod1()
{
    IPessoaFisica adv = new Advogado();
    adv.Cpf = "111.111.111-11"; //OK
    adv.Nome = "José da Silva"; //OK
    adv.Advogar(); //ERRO - IPessoaFisica não contém definição de Advogar.
               // Método esta na classe concreta Advogado,e não está declarado na interface IPessoaFisica.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Por mais que teu objeto seja construído como `Advogado` ele é declarado como `IPessoaFisica` o que torna acessíveis apenas os métodos da interface `IPessoaFiscia`. Para ter acesso ao método `Advogar` você precisará fazer uma das seguintes mudanças:

Opção 1- Declarar o método advogar na interface `IPessoaFisica`

Opção 2- Mudar o tipo da variável adv para `Advogado`:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Advogado adv = new Advogado();
    adv.Cpf = "111.111.111-11";
    adv.Nome = "José da Silva";
    adv.Advogar();
}
```

Interfaces são utilizadas para permitir construir abstrações comuns de objetos e assim utilizar polimorfismo. Isso só é útil quando os métodos polimórficos são declarados na interface pois aí você pode operar em variáveis declaradas com o tipo das interfaces. Quando você precisar utilizar métodos específicos que não podem ser abstraídos e consequentemente não podem ser declarados nas interfaces é necessário operar em variáveis com o tipo da implementação concreta para permitir o acesso aos seus métodos concretos.

Comment: Obrigado Giuliana. Sei que se fizer quaisquer das opções que vc citou vou conseguir acessar o método Advogar(). 

Contudo, a ideia era poder "plugar" em IPessoaFisica qualquer tipo de pessoa. Ou seja, um advogado, uma juiz, ou qualquer outro tipo de pessoa física. Mas acessar os métodos específicos da classe concreta. 

Tb não quero declarar diretamente a classe concreta visando diminuir o acoplamento.

Comment: Então você poderia declarar na tua interface o método exercerProfissao, aí daria pra implementá-lo como advogar, "juizar", etc... Daria certo pra você assim?

Comment: Parece ser uma boa ideia. :)

Comment: @LéoB Tem algum problema em declarar a variável como `IPessoaFisica` e depois converter para o tipo concreto?

Comment: Tem se o @LéoB quiser que o método TestMethod1 seja polimórfico.

Comment: Considere uma interface sempre do seguinte modo: O que é comum em vários objetos para que eu possa abstrair em uma interface, neste modo a sua interface nunca poderá ter algo que seja exclusivo do objeto final! Muito bom comentário @GiulianaBezerra !!!